# Integrate an array into a subroutine in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to vba and I'm trying to create a subroutine that will perform the same copy and paste operation to 5 workbooks.

I'm trying to do this by building an array containing all of the windows that the function needs to be carried out on as per the below:

```
Sub Copyinforevised()
Dim i As Integer
Dim z As Integer
i = 1
z = 5
Dim wb(i To z) As Window
wb (1): Set wb1 = Windows("Chariot OPS project workbook.xlsx")
wb (2): Set wb2 = Windows("Chariot RAN project workbook.xlsx")
wb (3): Set wb3 = Windows("Chariot AT project workbook.xlsx")
wb (4): Set wb4 = Windows("Chariot OSS project workbook.xlsx")
wb (5): Set wb5 = Windows("Chariot MOB project workbook.xlsx")
For i = 1 To z
    Windows(wb(i)).Activate
[function to be done to the workbook]
Next i
End Sub
```

But when I try to run the macro I get the error "compile error constant expression queried"

Comment: I think you need `Workbooks` instead of `Windows`. Also `wb1` etc is not part of the array. So something like `Set wb(1) = Application.Workbooks("Chariot OPS project workbook.xlsx")` makes more sense. In your loop you can also then use `wb(i).Activate` without using `Windows`

Comment: @AlexdeJong: Not good idea to use `.Activate`. You don't need to do that as you already have the object. There are many examples on the net which will go into details why we should never use `.Activate` or `.Select`. Please have a read

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working syntax:

```
Sub Copyinforevised()
Dim i As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim wb

i = 1
z = 5

ReDim wb(i To z) As Window

Set wb(1) = Windows("Chariot OPS project workbook.xlsx")
Set wb(2) = Windows("Chariot RAN project workbook.xlsx")
Set wb(3) = Windows("Chariot AT project workbook.xlsx")
Set wb(4) = Windows("Chariot OSS project workbook.xlsx")
Set wb(5) = Windows("Chariot MOB project workbook.xlsx")
End Sub
```

Note the use of `ReDim`.

Comment: Would the `Set` throw an error if the workbook is not open?

Comment: @Zac .................yes................you need a captioned Window Object............

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - I haven't really seen `Windows()` before. Is that a suggested way to use this, or is it perhaps better practice to set these as actual `Workbook` variables?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting a bunch of `Workbook` variables (which is certainly a way to do this), you could put your workbook names in to an array, and use that to loop through:

```
Sub Copyinforevised()
Dim wbList() As Variant
wbList = Array("Chariot OPS project workbook.xlsx", "Chariot RAN project workbook.xlsx", _
    "Chariot AT project workbook.xlsx", "Chariot OSS project workbook.xlsx", _
    "Chariot MOB project workbook.xlsx")

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(wbList) To UBound(wbList)
    With Workbooks(wbList(i))
        ' Do whatever with the workbook
        Debug.Print .Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

(And just a note these workbooks must be open.)